# android Quick Search Box problem

Tags: android, quick-search

i want to add a QSB in my activity which will show search result from a list of string variables with in my activity.Can anyone know how can i do this.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/topics/search/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: yes i have gone through it but i want to do application search or web search. i want the search items will be provided myself . i mean i want to search the items a fixed list with strings.